# Python loop to calculate sum of elements in a list except 13

Tags: python, list, loops, sum

I am trying to write a function that iterates through a list to return the sum of the integer elements in the list. However if there is a 13 in the list, it needs to exclude the 13 and whatever comes right after it from the sum. So far I have come up with the following code. This works for almost all cases except when there are two 13's back to back. It only excludes the two 13's instead of the two 13's plus whatever is after the second 13. For example, when I call the function with `print(sum13([13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]))`, instead of giving the output of `11` it gives `13`. Any help is appreciated.

```
    def sum13(nums):

      while 13 in nums:
          index13 = nums.index(13)
          nums = nums[0:index13]+nums[index13+2:]
      return sum(nums)
```

Comment: by your logic first 13 should omit the second 13( "it needs to exclude the 13 and WHATEVER comes right after it"), therefore 2 +5+6 = 13

Comment: It needs to omit whatever comes after each 13 as well as the 13 itself. So in this case it should be omitting the 2 as well from the list.

Comment: I do understand what you want, but what i am saying is a reflection of your logic, I am trying to help you see where you made a mistake :-).first 13 omits second 13, therefore second 13 can not omit 2.

Comment: Yeah I understand why it is happening but I need help figuring out a fix

Comment: recursion might be a choice

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of doing something like this is to keep track of the previous variable, for example:

```
def sum13(nums):
    prev = None
    my_sum = 0 
    for ele in nums:
        if ele != 13 and prev != 13: 
            my_sum += ele 
        prev = ele 
    return my_sum

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(sum13([1,2,13,3,4]))
    print(sum13([13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]))
```

Result:

```
7
11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it functionally:

```
def sum13(nums):
    return sum(current
               for current, following
               in zip(nums, [None] + nums[:-1])
               if current != 13 and following != 13)
```

"Gimme a sum of all numbers that are not 13, and whose next number is not 13".

Comment: don't use python built-ins as variable names, `next` - even if 'safe' inside the generator it looks bad in python aware colorized editors

Comment: @f5r5e5d: Fair. I never remember if something is or isn't a Python built-in. It's one of the many reasons I can't like Python more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slice to determine whether a 13 precedes a number:

```
def sum13(nums):
    sum_ = 0
    for index, elem in enumerate(nums):
        if 13 not in nums[max(index-1, 0):index+1]:
            sum_ += elem
    return sum_
```

The `max` is needed only for the first element, being that `i-1` would be `0-1`, so the slice would be `[-1:1]`, which is empty. You can even cut it down to one line, if you really wanted to:

```
sum(e for i, e in enumerate(nums) if 13 not in nums[max(i-1, 0):i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because generators need love too:

```
l = [13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]

def sanitize(list):
    il = iter(list)
    for e in il:
        while e == 13:
            e = next(il)
            if e != 13:
                e = next(il)
        yield e

print(sum(sanitize(l)))
```

The idea being that you clean up your list first and then sum it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Note that this is using nexted function to remove 13s, or a series of 13s and the number right after

```
def refine(nums, index_i):
    while 13 in nums:
        print(nums)
        index = len(nums) - nums[::-1].index(13) - 1
        if index == index_i -1:
            nums = refine(nums[0:index] + nums[index+1:], index)
        else:
            nums = refine(nums[0:index] + nums[index+2:], index)
    return nums

    print( sum(refine([0, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 13, 5, 6, 13], 0)) )
```

This will sum only `[0, 2, 3, 4, 6]`

However, this is assuming you have a small list to manage With large list, you might want to think of the performance of such manipulation